# Trimming variable text from string lines

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to trim strings in a large text document. They all begin with `>chr5:` and then a variable string of numbers.

For example: `>chr5:1264398-1264827`. I want to trim these all down to just say `>chr5`. The number sequences likely differ by length, so I'm unsure if I can just trim down X number of characters and have it work for each applicable line in the document.

I have tried

```bsh
sed -i 's/>chr5*/>chr5/g' file.txt
```

in an attempt to wildcard each line that starts with `>chr5`, but this did not work. It didn't seem to do anything. I've searched around online but can't find anything that deals with deleting a variable string region.

I'm working on a Mac Terminal if that's important. Let me know if there's anything I need to elaborate on, and thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but asterisk `*` in sed (or more accurately regexp regular expression in this context) means zero or more of the preceding character. A full stop/period `.` means any character so if you ran:

`sed -i 's/>chr5.*/>chr5/g' file.txt`

it means match zero or more of any character and would likely do what you are expecting.

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much.